# PhD in operator algebras and non-commutative geometry

Tags: soft-question, oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

I do not know whether it is a good place to ask this question or not.

I want to PhD in operator algebras and non-commutative geometry. What are the best places in the world for that? I want a good research group rather than some single or two persons working in that area. And I will prefer anywhere in Europe.

Comment: Texas A&M. Not in Europe, but hard to beat.

Comment: Kevin, I think TAM is great for op alg, but NCG? Really?

Comment: Find out what kind of problems you want to work on...then pick where to go. OA and NCG is not specific enough, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Alain Connes is currently Professor at the Collège de France.  Shoot big and go for the gold, I'd say.

otherwise, a team that has done some great work in synthesizing noncommutative geometry with other fields has been the Free University in Brussels.  They have an amazing program there with prodigous output.

Comment: The formulation 'at the Collège de France, IHES' is in my opinion confusing and possibly based on a misunderstanding. He is at the Collège de France and at the IHES (and somewhere in the US, too, I think). In any case the Collège de France is one thing the IHES a different one.

Comment: @quid: You are right.  I hadn't meant to put IHES, but I had wanted to get the accent and just copied the name so I'd use the right Unicode.  I had accidentally copied too much and didn't notice.  I didn't want the post grad research institute.  :(

Comment: il est à Vanderbilt


Comment: Here are some places in Europe with very good and reasonably big research groups in operator algebras and non-commutative geometry: 
- Paris Jussieu (G. Skandalis,M. Hilsum, A. Zuk, E. Blanchard, etc.);
- Orléans (V. Lafforgue, J. Renault, etc.);
- Metz (J.-L. Tu, M. Benameur, H. Oyono, etc.);
- Marseille (Puschnig, etc.);
- Muenster (J. Cuntz, S. Echterhoff, etc.);
- Goettingen (R. Meyer,etc.);
- Coppenhagen (R. Nest, Kirchberg, etc.).



Comment: Benameur is no longer in Metz. He is now in Montpellier. 

Comment: penn-state in usa paul baum is there,vanderblit jones,kasparov,connes spends few months there.In UK there is lancaster university(martin lindsay,many others check their website),glassgow(joachim zacharius),
cardiff university(David E.Evans) these are all I know.


Comment: evans works in operator algebra and TQFT
